# convert a variable to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have this Variable :

```
$value = '"item_id"=>"null","parent_id"=>"none","depth"=>0,"left"=>"1","right"=>18';
```

And I want get item_id and other element from top Variable with Array method, so i write this :

```
$value_arr = array($value);
$item_id = $value_arr["item_id"];
```

but i get error `Notice: Undefined index: item_id in file.php on line 115`

but When i use this method i get fine result successfully :

```
$value_arr = array("item_id"=>"null","parent_id"=>"none","depth"=>0,"left"=>"1","right"=>18);
$item_id = $value_arr["item_id"];
```

How i can solve this problem ?

**Note:** i don't want use 2'nd method because my Variables is Dynamic

## UPDATE:

Vincent answered that i must use json_decode and i want to ask another question for better way because my original string that i have is :

```
[
{"item_id":null,"parent_id":"none","depth":0,"left":"1","right":18},
{"item_id":"1","parent_id":null,"depth":1,"left":2,"right":7},
{"item_id":"3","parent_id":null,"depth":1,"left":2,"right":7}
]
```

With this information whats the better way for get `item_id`, `parent_id` and ... ?

Comment: What do you mean your "Variables is Dynamic" ? You can change values of an array you know?

Comment: How do you get that variable in the first place?

Comment: I'm updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) with second parameter as `TRUE` to get an associative array as result:

```
$json = json_decode($str, TRUE);    
for ($i=0; $i < count($json); $i++) { 
    $item_id[$i] = $json[$i]['item_id'];
    $parent_id[$i] = $json[$i]['parent_id'];
    // ...
}
```

If you want to do it using a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['item_id']."\n";
    echo $value['parent_id']."\n";
    // ...
}
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/51708)

Comment: i get this code with your help :

    Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [item_id] => [parent_id] => none [depth] => 0 [left] => 1 [right] => 18 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [item_id] => 1 [parent_id] => [depth] => 1 [left] => 2 [right] => 7 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [item_id] => 7 [parent_id] => 1 [depth] => 2 [left] => 3 [right] => 4 )
)

Comment: and use this foreach ($json as $key=>$value) {}  | now how i can get item_id ?

Comment: @EbadGhafoory: Does the `for` loop not satisfy your requirements? You can simply `echo $item_id[1];` outside the loop, and it'd print the value.

Comment: @EbadGhafoory: I've updated the answer with the `foreach` version, too :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$value = '"item_id"=>"null","parent_id"=>"none","depth"=>0,"left"=>"1","right"=>18';
```

Is not a PHP array, you will need to convert that to an array by exploding it on `"=>"` and `","` and remove any extra `"`'s you find.

You should be using JSON however and using `json_encode` and `json_decode`

Comment: Better yet, prevent whatever is creating that array-ish string and just use the array. If you really need to work a string then serialize the variable - don't come up with your own serialization strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You should use JSON encoding and use the json_decode method if you want something dynamic. JSON is a good standard for dynamic data.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

I tested this for you:

```
<?php
$value = '"item_id"=>"null","parent_id"=>"none","depth"=>0,"left"=>"1","right"=>18';
eval("\$value_arr = array($value);");
print_r($value_arr);
?>
```

Please check. PHP::**eval**() is used. It worked.

Comment: This *will* work but in general `eval()` [should be avoided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php/951868).

Comment: @Mike B, I agree that eval() should be avoided if one handles user input string. There is no risk if the code is from the developer's side.

Comment: Keep reading. There are plenty of reasons outside of code maintainability and security to avoid eval. eval()`ed code can not be opcode cached.

Comment: @Mike B, The opcode cache is a good argument. Nevertheless, eval() is the simplest way to accomplish this task...

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution could be:

```
$array = json_decode( '{' . str_ireplace( '=>', ':', $value ) . '}', true );
// Array ( [item_id] => null [parent_id] => none [depth] => 0 [left] => 1 [right] => 18 )
```

**EDIT:** In regards to the update of the question.

Your input is a json_encoded array. simply json_decode it and you're done.

```
json_decode( $value, true );
```

Comment: You'll find issues with the `"null"` string (rather then a null empty value). A better solution would be to fix the generator of that array.

Comment: Well, of course i would consider figuring out why i am facing with such non-standard variable in the first place. Although what you're suggesting is not a flaw in my example. The input is "null" so as the output. Try without the quotes on null and you'll get the empty string instead. json_decode handles it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution you are looking for:

```
<?php
     $value = '"item_id"=>"null","parent_id"=>"none","depth"=>0,"left"=>"1","right"=>18';
     $arr = explode(',',$value);
     foreach($arr as $val)
     {
      $tmp = explode("=>",$val);
      $array[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
     }
   print_r($array);
?>
```

And this will output something like:

```
Array ( ["item_id"] => "null" ["parent_id"] => "none" ["depth"] => 0 ["left"] => "1" ["right"] => 18 )
```